# Add the BSDA package

Tags: r

I was trying to add the BSDA package to do the sign test. However, every time I tried to add this package as follows:

```
> library("BSDA")
```

An error message printed out as:

```
Error in library("BSDA") : there is no package called ‘BSDA’
```

Am I using a non-existing package? How could I do the sign test without this package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are using a non-installed package. The easiest way to fix this is to

```
install.packages("BSDA")
```

Comment: Well, I succeeded in adding the package. But when I used the SIGN.test it said "could find function "SIGN.test" Calls". How to deal with this issue?

Comment: That's a different question :) You should mark this as answered and open another to keep it all clean. Try searching for that error as well. Good luck.